# Carbon date format not returning correct diffInDays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, php-carbon

My date looks like this: `28/01/2022`.

I'd like to find out difference in years, months, days from `now()` time.

I tried:

1) Not working, because it says my date is illegal format.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInYears(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date))
```

2) This gives me huge number; something like 878 when it should be just 24.

```
$dateObject = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
return \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($dateObject);
```

What else can I try?

Comment: It's 2019, you've got a date in 2022, why would diffInDays give 24?

Comment: You're right. I should have asked otherwise. I have 2 dates and I want to know the difference in years,days,months, not separately, but together. So if I use all the differences I will get 2-878-26orsomething

Comment: Carbon backs onto DateTime, so can you not just call [diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)? The returned [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) / CarbonInterval object should contain the separated values.

Comment: Thanks Man. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$difference = $date1->longRelativeDiffForHumans($date2, 3);
dd($difference);
```

This should give you something with this format:

> 3 years, 7 months, 2 weeks after

The signature of the method is as follows:

> ```
> longRelativeDiffForHumans(DateTimeInterface | null $other = null, int $parts = 1)
> ```

As you can see the `$parts` argument tells the granularity of the response (in my example I put `3`: *years, months, days*).

Check the [Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) for more info.